# Flutter - Image URL sometimes doesn't return an image

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm parsing JSON and have a `thumbnail` key.

Further, I'm using `CacheNetworkImage` to load the image.

```
            Container(
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: article.thumbnail,
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => ErrorWidget(), // When the thumbnail key has null value
                imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                  //trimmed
              ),
            ),
```

Though, sometimes, there is no image at the parsed url

1. http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/kdnuggets-data-mining-analytics/~4/kCxWsMO4Czg
2. https://st1.ning.com/topology/rest/1.0/file/get/3668586163?profile=RESIZE_710x

Second URL gives me a valid image and first one doesn't. So, how can I handle this case? How can I show my ErrorWidget(), if the thumbnail has first url as value.

Comment: You mean don't need to make a request if the URL is an error for the last request?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use errorWidget property

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        errorWidget: (context, uri, error) => Image.asset(
               'assets/not_loaded_placeholder.png',
                width: imageBorderHeight,
                height: imageBorderHeight),
        width: imageBorderHeight,
        height: imageBorderHeight,
        imageUrl: imageUrl),
```